# including different php file if is/ isnt IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, include

I want to include a nice uploader for all browsers that will support it (everything but IE, of course).

Im trying to use conditional statements like so:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<?php include("image-upload-test2.php"); ?>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
<?php include("image-upload-test3.php"); ?>
<![endif]-->
```

but the included files doesn't show up on the page, looking a the source they are commented out? how do i get around this?

Comment: PHP is processed server-side, conditional comments are processed client-side. You can't combine those.

Comment: If anything on your server side depends on the client's browser - you're doing it wrong. Find a way to handle this client side, not with PHP includes.

Answer (score 3):

Use feature detection. Even if the above did work, IE no longer supports conditional comments as of version 10.

Comment: You don't. Whatever upload system you have should be client-side. Load the "advanced" system, and in the JavaScript for it check the features. If a feature is not supported then redirect (or better modify the DOM) to get the "basic" one.

Comment: @Kolink Wouldn't it make more sense to load the basic system, and modify the DOM if the browser is supported to use the advanced system? This way it could (depending on how this all works) gracefully degrade when JS is disabled as well.

Comment: @ColinMorelli That's true, but honestly in this day and age anyone without JavaScript shouldn't be surprised that the Internet doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_browser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) to detect the browser your visitor use

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo $browser['browser'] . "\n\n";
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Comment: Whats wrong with this advice? He asked how to detect IE serverside and thats how to do it..

Comment: nothing wrong! however, the point is: usingone javascript file that supports all browser is recommended, but: this is not easy for beginners, then, using jQuery or similar tools is the solution.

Comment: Yes and no - sure its a good style to decide clientside what to do, but if you act this way, you have everytime the probably huge overhead for cross browser comaptible versions, even if you don't need them. This isn't important on desktop pc, but if you have a mobile device with low bandwidth and slow cpu, this becomes way important